# why is my rss feed written with php not readable by itunes?

Tags: php, rss, itunes, feed, podcast

I am trying to sync my rss feed with the podcast section of iTunes. Would somebody be able to help me and tell me why my rss feed is not syncing with itunes? I researched potential issues and didn't seem to find anything that would conflict with my feed. here is the feed

http://www.sportdebaters.com/content/sdrss.php

Comment: the recommendation here may help: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sportdebaters.com%2Fcontent%2Fsdrss.php

Comment: You could also try to send it with a `header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8')` instead of `text/xml`.

Comment: I didn't know feed validation services existed! that's awesome. but the recommendations they provided... I don't quite understand what they mean...

Comment: still need help.. added a `<guid>$var</guid>` to the feed... still nothing with itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used iTunes specific rss tags

take a look at http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html and http://www.podcast411.com/howto_1.html

Comment: itunes said that the itunes specific tags are completely optional and only necessary to optimize the search results. I just want to get it readable by itunes and then ill give it some SEO with the itunes tags

Comment: apparently `<enclosure url="http://example.com/podcasts/everything/AllAboutEverythingEpisode2.mp3" length="5650889" type="audio/mpeg"/>
` was necessary....

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit hard to get hard, so I've created a small open source library for this.

You can download and learn how to use it [here](https://github.com/read2me-online/itunes-podcast-feed-php), but let me c/p an example nonetheless:

```
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Channel;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\FeedGenerator;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Item;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// SETUP CHANNEL
$title = 'Read2Me Daily Curated Articles';
$link = 'https://read2me.online';
$author = 'NYTimes and Medium';
$email = 'hello@read2me.online';
$image = 'https://d22fip447qchhd.cloudfront.net/api/widget/static/images/default-thumbnail.png';
$explicit = false;
$categories = [
    'News',
    'Technology',
    'Culture',
    'Entrepreneurship',
    'Productivity'
];
$description = 'Daily curated articles from New York Times and Medium';
$lang = 'en';
$copyright = 'The New York Times Company and The Medium Company';
$ttl = 43200; // 12 hours in seconds

$channel = new Channel(
    $title, $link, $author, $email,
    $image, $explicit, $categories,
    $description, $lang, $copyright, $ttl
);

// SETUP EPISODE
$title = "Trump Says Disclosure of Mueller Questions in Russia Probe Is ‘Disgraceful’";
$fileUrl = 'https://s3.read2me.online/audio/www-nytimes-com-2018-05-01-us-politics-trump-mueller-russia-questions-html-7e9601.mp3';
$duration = '2:18';
$description = 'WASHINGTON — President Trump on Tuesday said it was “disgraceful” that questions the special counsel would like to ask him were publicly disclosed, and he incorrectly noted that there were no questions about collusion. The president also said collusion was a “phony” crime.';
$date = 1525177808;
$filesize = 828387;
$mime = 'audio/mpeg';

$item = new Item(
    $title, $fileUrl, $duration,
    $description, $date, $filesize, $mime
);
$item2 = clone $item; // just to give you an idea of how it works

// SETUP FEED
$feed = new FeedGenerator($channel, ...[$item, $item2]);

// OUTPUT XML
print $feed->getXml();
```